# Jenkins extended choice parameter groovy script is not working

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, extended-choice-parameter

I have to pass the build number from other job to a pipeline job. Below is my pipeline syntax page:

[image: jenkins_pipeline_syntax]

I have generated the below script:

```
    properties([parameters([<object of type com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended_choice_parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition>])])
```

Below image is the script generated:
[image]

But i am not able to use this properly. Please help, how to use the generated script for extended choice paramater.

Comment: Why do you need extended choice parameter plugin for this ?

Comment: I am running a groovy script to get the build from another job. Hence i am using the extended choice parameter plugin

Comment: Declared Pipeline not support it, but Scripted Pipeline does.  Example code can 
 refer http://www.matfre.com/jenkins-blog14.html

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar plugin for the same goal - [Extensible Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin).

The following syntax works for me using this plugin:

```
properties([
        [$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty', parameterDefinitions: [
                [$class            : 'ExtensibleChoiceParameterDefinition',
                 name              : 'ParameterName',
                 description       : 'ParameterDescription',
                 editable          : 'false',
                 choiceListProvider: [$class      : 'SystemGroovyChoiceListProvider',
                                      groovyScript: [script: 'GroovyScriptAsString']
                 ]
                ]
        ]
        ]
])
```